# Multiple Graphics2D Objects

Tags: java, swing, components, graphics2d

I have a Graphics object of JPanel and that is working fine:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GraphicsTest extends JPanel
{
    private Graphics2D g2d;
    private String state;
    private int x, y;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setClip(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString("STATE: " + state, 5, 15);
        g2d.drawString("Mouse Position: " + x + ", " + y, 5, 30);

        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        Rectangle2D r2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(x,y,10,10);
        g2d.draw(r2d);
        Test t = new Test();
        super.add(t);

        repaint();
    }

    public void setState(String state) { this.state = state; }
    public String getState() { return state; }

    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
}
```

I was experimenting with a new Graphics component and when I instantiate a new Test and add it in GraphicsTest nothing happens. What is it that I am doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Test extends JComponent
{
    private Graphics2D g2d;
    private String state;
    private int x, y;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(60, 60,
                10, 10));

        repaint();
    }

    public void setState(String state) { this.state = state; }
    public String getState() { return state; }

    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add Test component only once and set a layout:

```
public GraphicTest()
{
    super();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new Test(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Also, do not save `Graphics2D` objects because they will be invalid once `paintComponent` is finished and do not call `repaint` inside `paintComponent`. Use timers if you need animation and call `repaint` in `setXXX` methods that change the look of the component.

Comment: So then is it no possible to draw a new graphics object on top of a JPanel?

Comment: The Test component can have its own paintComponent method that draws something. You may want to make it transparent using `setOpaque(false)` method.

Comment: How do I add it to the JPanel though?

Comment: To add child component use `add` method. See the answer.

Comment: Check the size and coordinates of the sub-component in debugger (`getSize` and `getLocation` methods). You need to either use a layout (recommended approach) or manage its size and position relative to parent component manually.